# how could I take advantage of both State and Writer in haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

when I went through the last chapter of LYAH and met with [ListZipper](http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers#focusing-on-lists), I gave myself an assignment that to make it a State monad so that the source code would look more clear like:

```
manipList = do
    goForward
    goForward
    goBack
```

and at the same time, I wanted to keep a log for this process by taking advantage of Writer monad, but I didn't know how to combine these two Monads together.

My solution was to keep a [String] inside the state, and my source code is

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State

type ListZipper a = ([a], [a])

-- move focus forward, put previous root into breadcrumbs
goForward :: ListZipper a -> ListZipper a
goForward (x:xs, bs) = (xs, x:bs)

-- move focus back, restore previous root from breadcrumbs
goBack :: ListZipper a -> ListZipper a
goBack (xs, b:bs) = (b:xs, bs)

-- wrap goForward so it becomes a State
goForwardM :: State (ListZipper a) [a]
goForwardM = state stateTrans where
    stateTrans z = (fst newZ, newZ) where
        newZ = goForward z

-- wrap goBack so it becomes a State
goBackM :: State (ListZipper a) [a]
goBackM = state stateTrans where
    stateTrans z = (fst newZ, newZ) where
        newZ = goBack z

-- here I have tried to combine State with something like a Writer
-- so that I kept an extra [String] and add logs to it manually

-- nothing but write out current focus
printLog :: Show a => State (ListZipper a, [String]) [a]
printLog = state $ \(z, logs) -> (fst z, (z, ("print current focus: " ++ (show $ fst z)):logs))

-- wrap goForward and record this move
goForwardLog :: Show a => State (ListZipper a, [String]) [a]
goForwardLog = state stateTrans where
    stateTrans (z, logs) = (fst newZ, (newZ, newLog:logs)) where
        newZ = goForward z
        newLog = "go forward, current focus: " ++ (show $ fst newZ)

-- wrap goBack and record this move
goBackLog :: Show a => State (ListZipper a, [String]) [a]
goBackLog = state stateTrans where
    stateTrans (z, logs) = (fst newZ, (newZ, newLog:logs)) where
        newZ = goBack z
        newLog = "go back, current focus: " ++ (show $ fst newZ)

-- return
listZipper :: [a] -> ListZipper a
listZipper xs = (xs, [])

-- return
stateZipper :: [a] -> (ListZipper a, [String])
stateZipper xs = (listZipper xs, [])

_performTestCase1 = do
    goForwardM
    goForwardM
    goBackM

performTestCase1 =
    putStrLn $ show $ runState _performTestCase1 (listZipper [1..4])

_performTestCase2 = do
    printLog
    goForwardLog
    goForwardLog
    goBackLog
    printLog

performTestCase2 = do
    let (result2, (zipper2, log2)) = runState _performTestCase2 $ stateZipper [1..4]
    putStrLn $ "Result: " ++ (show result2)
    putStrLn $ "Zipper: " ++ (show zipper2)
    putStrLn "Logs are: "
    mapM_ putStrLn (reverse log2)
```

But the problem is that I don't think this is a good solution since I have to maintain my logs manually. Is there any alternative way of mixing State monad and Writer monad so that they could work together?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're looking for [monad transformers](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers). The basic idea is to define a type like `WriterT` which takes another monad and combines it with a `Writer` creating a new type (like `WriterT log (State s)`).

Note: there is a convention that transformer types end with a capital `T`. So `Maybe` and `Writer` are normal monads and `MaybeT` and `WriterT` are their transformer equivalents.

The core idea is very simple: for a bunch of monads, you can easily imagine combining their behavior on bind. The simplest example is `Maybe`. Recall that all that `Maybe` does is propagate `Nothing` on bind:

```
Nothing >>= f = Nothing
Just x >>= f = f x
```

So it should be easy to imagine extending *any* monad with this behavior. All we do is check for `Nothing` first and then use the old monad's bind. The `MaybeT` type does exactly this: it wraps an existing monad and prefaces each bind with a check like this. You would also have to implement `return` by essentially wrapping the value in a `Just` and then using the inner monad's `return`. There is also a bit more plumbing to get everything to work, but this is the important idea.

You can imagine a very similar behavior for `Writer`: first we combine any new output then we use the old monad's bind. This is essentially the behavior of `WriterT`. There are some other details involved, but the basic idea is fairly simple and useful.

Monad transformers are a very common way to "combine" monads like you want. There are versions of most commonly used monads as transformers, with the notable exception of `IO` which always has to be at the base of your monad stack. In your case, both `WriterT` and `StateT` exist and could be used for your program.

Comment: that's exactly what I want! I've tried and both of them(WriterT & StateT) work well, ty!

Answer (score 13):

Tikhon Jelvis gives a nice answer with monad transformers. However, there is a quick solution also.

The [`Control.Monad.RWS`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.0.1.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-RWS-Lazy.html) module in `mtl` exports the `RWS` monad, which is a combination of the `Reader`, `Writer` and `State` monads.